# Excel VBA Select Option Website Dropdown List

Tags: vba, excel, browser-automation

I am trying to automate this website using VBA excel. I am stuck at one point where I need to select value from the drop-down box. I am very much new to this as this is my first such project.
This is what I have coded to select the value:

```
Set objSelect = objIE.document.getElementById("personTitle")

For Each opt In objSelect.Options
If opt.Value = "Miss" Then
    'Debug.Print "found!"

    opt.Selected = True
    'opt.Selected = "selected"
Else
    'Debug.Print "not found!"

    opt.Selected = False
End If
Next
```

I have also tried using the debug.print to check if the value that I am trying to find is actually getting matched or not- and it turns out that it matches. 
The only problem I am facing is that the value is not getting set. 
Can any of the gurus here please help?

Here is the HTML of that section:

```html
<div class="input-wrap input-wrap__inline">

            <div tabindex="-1" class="select is-placeholder"><div class="select_display">Title</div><div class="select_arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></div><dl class="select_list"><dt class="pretend-dd is-hover" data-index="1" data-val="Mr">Mr</dt><dt class="pretend-dd" data-index="2" data-val="Mrs">Mrs</dt><dt class="pretend-dd" data-index="3" data-val="Miss">Miss</dt><dt class="pretend-dd" data-index="4" data-val="Ms">Ms</dt><dt class="pretend-dd" data-index="5" data-val="Dr">Dr</dt></dl></div><select name="personTitle" class="parsley-validated hasCustomSelect .no-change, .bv-dropdown-select is-invisible" id="personTitle" required="" data-required-message="Please select a title">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Title</option>
                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
            </select>

     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a different class. The class in that HTML snippet is `select_list`. Then the subsequent `dt` tags.

If you observe the following CSS selector, where ["."](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) means class and [" dt"](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) means select all `dt` tags inside elements of that class, you will see it makes the correct selections:

[image: CSS selector]

In the code below, I translate this selector into:

```
ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("select_list")(0).getElementsByTagName("dt")
```

This assumes that index 0 is the correct one to use for elements of the class `"select_list"`. You can easily inspect the collection to find the right index if you set it to a variable e.g.

```
Dim x As Object
Set x = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("select_list")(0).getElementsByTagName("dt")
```

---

**Code:**

```
Dim currentOption As Object
For Each currentOption In ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("select_list")(0).getElementsByTagName("dt")
    If InStr(currentOption.innerText, "Miss") > 0 Then
        currentOption.Selected = True
    End If
Next currentOption
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options to try if you haven't already:

```
If opt.Value = "Miss" Then
'Debug.Print "found!"
opt.Click
```

OR

```
If opt.Value = "Miss" Then
'Debug.Print "found!"
opt.Focus
opt.FireEvent ("onchange")
```

If this turns out to be something done in kendoGrid or kendoDropDownList, I might be able to help with that also.